# Giant's Wrath and Full Attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The Spell Giant's Wrath (Spell Compendium, p. 105)  states you can throw one of the enchanted pebbles as an attack action.

Does that mean I can throw multiple pebbles as a full Attack provided I have a sufficiently high BAB or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If you look at a [full-attack description on the d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullAttack):

> If you get more than one attack per round because your base attack
>   bonus is high enough, because you fight with two weapons or a double
>   weapon or for some special reason you must use a full-round action to
>   get your additional attacks. You do not need to specify the targets of
>   your attacks ahead of time. You can see how the earlier attacks turn
>   out before assigning the later ones.

So if you do have multiple attacks, you can use each of them to throw a pebble.

Additionally, since you don't have to specify and you can see how earlier tacks resolve, you don't have to target the same creature with each separate attack.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Because this spell effects a number of pebbles that can be thrown as an 'attack action' rather then a standard action, you can indeed throw with iterative if you have them or dual wield toss them.